# Making the UINavigationBar Disappear and Appear on a touch, mimicking safari on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, safari, uinavigationbar

I have a `UIPageViewController` which is called from a `UITableViewController` and it shows a series of images to the user.

The images contain a lot of information and while it doesn't make sense to have a `UINavigationBar` the entire time, because it's just used to share the image, or go back, but is there a way to mimic Safari on iOS, where the `UINavigationBar` at the top disappears and reappears on a touch?

I have not tried anything because I honestly don't have the first clue on where to start with something like this. Is there a third-party open source framework, or an easy way to animate this? Perhaps in the viewDidLoad, have a timer on the `UINavigationBar`, to show it at the start and disappear after 2 seconds, etc, but then to reappear on a touch?

Any guidance on this would be really appreciated.

Comment: You can use tap gesture for show/hide UINavigationbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 8 provide default feature

```
self.navigationController.hidesBarsOnTap = true;
```

[Edited] Add tap gesture in viewDidLoad

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapHandle:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

Add Following method to your viewController

```
- (void)tapHandle:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender {
     dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden == NO) {
                [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
        }
        else{
                [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: For more default features you can follow this link which is in swift: http://natashatherobot.com/navigation-bar-interactions-ios8/

Comment: Apple Developer Document -> find "Hiding the Navigation Bar" from this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/hidesBarsOnTap

Comment: Pavan - thank you so much for the response. That one line of code is just brilliant and it works like a charm. Now to have a timer on this, how would i do this? So that when the view is displayed, it shows the bar and then hides it after 2 seconds?

Comment: Please don't use this self.navigationController.hidesBarsOnTap = true; for hide navigation after two seconds, Use edited answer. It works as your need.

Comment: Thanks very much Pavan - that's perfect and helpful! I appreciate your assistance with this.

Comment: Amit s Bajaj its my pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

Comment: The other answer was more appropriate